# how to store new elements added in webpage by user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I want to store user changes in my webpage so that user can go to next page then come back on that page so that elements which he added should be there when he comes back for editing the webpage. I do not want to store data to the database until he submits the form.

**let me explain with the example**

[in this image user add a new item to list by entering the name in input field I want to store these new items so that user can go to next and can come back with the list item present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omYHD.png)

Comment: Can you please read **[ask]**, especially the part about creating a **[mcve]**, and then update the question?  Once it's updated you are more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: What have you tried? You have tagged localStorage so I am assuming you have tried using that API to store your data. What was your attempt at using it?

Comment: I want to store webpage data for temporary purpose so I tag local storage. I want to store HTML new element which user added for temporary.

Comment: If you click the tag on your question, then click the "Learn more..." link, it shows what we call a Tag Wiki. That should have links to references, tutorials, etc., that can help you learn about the subject of the tag.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to set a cookie with all the changes you want to keep. If the user returns to the page later, restore the changes from the cookie.

Comment: Have a read though [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)